# How to write event log using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, event-log

I want to write event log when this vbscript run. How to i can?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like so:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.LogEvent 4, "Your Message Here"
```

The 4 is a severity level. You can learn more about the `LogEvent` method on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4ce6by3(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for helping. Where write log ? I don't find it

Comment: @Emree - It should write it to the event viewer. You can find that by running `compmgmt.msc` from the run dialog. Take a look around Google for the the event viewer.

Answer (score 1):

This is old but I'm sure still valid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4ce6by3

You also need permissions to be able to write to the event log so depending on the user running the script you may or my not have access.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Where write log ? I don't find it

Answer (score 1):

You might want to simply write to your own log file.

Check out my link with more information and details

http://www.yeshaib.com/2010/08/vbscript-in-the-logging/

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
'
' Please Enter Updates with date and name including line of Change
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------------------------------------------------------------------- 

 set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
 set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'--- Main Begins ---------------------------------------

 WriteToLog("Generic Log.vbs - Write This")

'--- Main Ends -----------------------------------------

'--- Write to log --------------------------------------
Sub WriteToLog(strLogMessage)
 Const ForAppending = 8
 Const vbsName = "Generic Log"

 strLogFileName = "C:\GenericLog.log"
 strLogEntryTime = NOW

 'test whether file exists To either write/append to file
 if objFSO.FileExists(strLogFileName) Then
 Set objLogFileTransaction = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strLogFileName, ForAppending)
 Else
 Set objLogFileTransaction = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strLogFileName)
 End if

 objLogFileTransaction.WriteLine strLogEntryTime &amp; chr(9) &amp; chr(58) &amp; chr(9) &amp; vbsName &amp; chr(9) &amp; chr(58) &amp; chr(9) &amp; strLogMessage
 objLogFileTransaction.Close
 WScript.StdOut.WriteLine strLogMessage
 WScript.StdOut.WriteLine ""
End Sub
```