# VBS To Event Log

Tags: vbscript

I have a script that I am currently using to check when that network goes up or down. Its writing to a pinglog.txt .

For the life of me I can not figure out how to get it to write to the event log when the network goes down. Where it says:

```
   Call logme(Time & " - "  & machine & " is not responding to ping, CALL FOR 

   HELP!!!!",strLogFile)
```

Thats what I need to write to the Event Log "Machine is not repsonding to ping, CALL FOR HELP!!!!

```
 'Ping multiple computers and log when one doesn't respond.
 '################### Configuration #######################

 'Enter the IPs or machine names on the line below separated by a semicolon
  strMachines = "4.2.2.2;8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4"

  'Make sure that this log file exists, if not, the script will fail.
   strLogFile = "c:\logs\pinglog.txt"

   '################### End Configuration ###################

   'The default application for .vbs is wscript. If you double-click on the script,
   'this little routine will capture it, and run it in a command shell with cscript.
    If Right(WScript.FullName,Len(WScript.FullName) - Len(WScript.Path)) <>       "\cscript.exe" Then
           Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:    {impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
        Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
        Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
        Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
        objProcess.Create WScript.Path + "\cscript.exe """ + WScript.ScriptFullName + """", Null, objConfig, intProcessID
    WScript.Quit
    End If

    Const ForAppending = 8
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If objFSO.FileExists(strLogFile) Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFile(strLogFile)
    Else
Wscript.Echo "Log file does not exist. Please create " & strLogFile
WScript.Quit
  End If

 aMachines = Split(strMachines, ";")

    Do While True 
    For Each machine In aMachines
            Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}")._
            ExecQuery("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '"_
            & machine & "'")
            For Each objStatus In objPing
                       If IsNull(objStatus.StatusCode) Or objStatus.StatusCode<>0 Then 
                                Call logme(Time & " - "  & machine & " is not responding to   ping, CALL FOR 

  HELP!!!!",strLogFile) 
                       Else
                                WScript.Echo(Time & " + "  & machine & " is responding to       ping, we are good")    
                    End If
               Next
        Next
        WScript.Sleep 5000
  Loop

  Sub logme(message,logfile)
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(logfile, ForAppending, True)
    objtextfile.WriteLine(message)
    WScript.Echo(message)
    objTextFile.Close
  End Sub
```

Sorry about the spacing in the code.  Thanks for the help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534407/how-to-write-event-log-using-vbscript

Comment: Doesnt help me I tried that and got a error message every single time.

Comment: What error message did you get?  That might indicate permissions problems

Comment: I was trying to add it here
         
  Call logme(Time & " - "  & machine & " is not responding to   ping, CALL FOR HELP!!!!",strLogFile) 

and i was getting it on line 45

Comment: Here's another SO link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887557/writing-to-the-windows-event-log-vbs?rq=1  Option Explicit seemed to help.

Comment: You still have't provided the error message you're getting. And you never even attempt to write to the eventlog. Did you mean "logfile" rather than "eventlog"? Also, why is there a line break in the string you're trying to log? Does that line break exist in your script as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the WshShell object:

> *object*.LogEvent(*intType*, *strMessage* [,*strTarget*])
>
> ***object*** WshShell object.
>
> ***intType*** Integer value representing the event type.
>
> ***strMessage*** String value containing the log entry text.
>
> ***strTarget*** Optional. String value indicating the name of the computer
>   system where the event log is stored (the default is the local
>   computer system). Applies to Windows NT/2000 only.

Like so:

```
Option Explicit

Dim shl

Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Call shl.LogEvent(1,"Some Error Message")

Set shl = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

The first argument to LogEvent is an event type:

> ```
> 0    SUCCESS
> 1    ERROR
> 2    WARNING
> 4    INFORMATION
> 8    AUDIT_SUCCESS
> 16   AUDIT_FAILURE
> ```

**EDIT**: more detail

Replace your entire 'logme' sub-routine with this

```
  Sub logme(t,m)
      Dim shl

      Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

      Call shl.LogEvent(t,m)

      Set shl = Nothing
  End Sub
```

Then change this line:

```
Call logme(Time & " - "  & machine & " is not responding to   ping, CALL FOR HELP!!!!",strLogFile)
```

To:

```
Call logme(1, machine & " is not responding to   ping, CALL FOR HELP!!!!")
```

Comment: How would I add that into the code I already have. Sorry I am not familiar with VBS at all.

Comment: I get a error that says
    Line 57
    Char 11
    Error Expected Identifier
    Code 800A03F2
Source Microsoft VBS Compilation Error

Comment: Sorry, `type` is a reserved word... I edited again and changed `(type,message)` to `(t,m)`