# send debug.print to different Immediate window

Tags: vba, debugging, ms-access, immediate-window

I have set up a multithreading routine in Access which opens up several Access files at the same time and executes a specific function in each file. The files act in parallel. I would like to send `Debug.Print` messages to the main file which initiates the multithreading.

I'm not sure if it can do this or if there is a better solution.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: see this (it logs to system log only) ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574317/vbs-to-event-log/19590044#19590044

Comment: what about named pipes?  i am not sure how to implement though.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of *processes*, each working on their own part of the *bigger picture*.

The *immediate pane* of the "main" IDE belongs to *that instance*, in *that process*; you could <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to bring up a VBE instance in any/every instance to view that instance's `Debug.Print` output.

What you want is something like an [`ILogger`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64109/23788) implementation that writes the log entries in a dedicated database table: a [`DatabaseLogger`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64122/23788), for example.

You replace `Debug.Print` with `Logger.Log` calls; that way you let the database server deal with the multiple incoming threads, and depending on the RDBMS you could even setup a job to cleanup, aggregate and/or archive the older log records. Or whatever, as long as it's not logic I need to care about in VBA code.

Writing to another VBE's *immediate* toolwindow involves <s>low-level, cross-process Win32</s> *wizardry* that doesn't need to clutter up an otherwise nice & tidy VBA project. I wouldn't bother with that, there are simpler solutions.

Comment: Hi Mat,logging is something that I had been considering. I will check the code out and see how it fits. thanks so much.

Comment: Hi Mat, those links are amazing. I was checking out the dictionary you created and then the updated dictionary. there is a reference to  in 
    {Private Type tDictionary Encapsulated As List }. should this also be "TYPE TypeValidator" or is it another class.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a PublicNotCreatable UserForm (not an Access Form) in the main application, and pass a reference to it, to all of the parallel apps. Add a custom method to the UserForm, like 'PrintLine(message as string)`, and each app can call`form.PrintLine("app is running")`?

You could then have the UserForm display the output, or possibly, have the UserForm output the message to the Immediate window of the main application.